# SIGABRT error in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm having trouble compiling this code in Swift successfully. Its a program for stopwatch. Two labels(start and stop) and a textfield as the output. It says its a delegate problem and highlights this in red:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
```

My code for the project is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer = NSTimer()
    var counter = 1

    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func updateCounter()
    {
        counter += 1
        Label.text = String(counter)
    }

    @IBAction func Start(sender: AnyObject)
        {
            counter = 0
            Label.text = String(counter)

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector ("updateCounter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }


    @IBAction func Stop(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        timer.invalidate()
    }

}
```

Comment: Code seems fine to me, just make sure all connections are proper or not.

Comment: Your code is correct, but make sure that IB Outlet is correctly connected. If the issue is still on , delete the IB Outlet and try to reconnect it !

Comment: @iAnurag I can't get my head around it really. Connections seem to be intact.

Comment: Try to delete it and reconnect

Comment: @ChathurangaSilva I tried that before. Just did again. Didn't work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very common problem, here's what you have to do:

1. Go through every outlet **on your storyboard** and delete it.
2. Reconnect every function in your ViewController to the outlets.

The problem, I believe, is that you have changed the name of an outlet in your code, and when the storyboard looks for that outlet it crashes your app. Make sure that when you rename your outlets, you reconnect it too!

Comment: Thanks so much Gabriel. I'd give that a shot once I'm on the computer and give you some feedback. I have a feeling this might work.

Comment: @DavidiTokuta Any luck?

Comment: Hey Gabriel! Sorry for the late reply. Yes it did work. And of course I'm delighted. Trying my best to learn as much as I can on Xcode. Hope all's good on your end.

Comment: @DavidiTokuta No Problem :) Enjoy learning Xcode, and stick with it!